# Build Error + Creating VSTO addin for excel 2010

Tags: msbuild, vsto, excel-2010, msbuild-task, excel-addins

I try to create an excel add-in using VS 2010. When I create a new project Excel 2010 Addin, and try to compile the solution. I get an error which says.

```
'Error  1   The "FindRibbons" task could not be loaded from the assembly            
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks, 
'Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Confirm that the   
'<UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are   
'available, and that the task contains a public class that implements   
'Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.   DemoExcelAddIn1
```

I downloaded an installed the VS 2010 tools for office runtime. But I cannot locate the assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks,

How do I proceed. Could anyone help..

Comment: I found no ways on obtaining the missing assembly. I upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 and the error disappeared. Could anyone help me on fixing the issue with Vs 2010

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like a [known issue sourced from MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/848b773a-2933-4371-a98f-f4346c427aed#50d7014c-c9c4-4605-a7bc-4beef6d172ad) - you just need to update your `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets` file to  point to version `11.0.0.0` instead of version `10.0.0.0`.

#### Updating MSBuild Targets File

> For those who encounter this problem, go to **C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\OfficeTools** and open the **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets** file. 
> Replace all **10.0.0.0** with **11.0.0.0**.

Comment: Edit  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets file and replace Replace all 10.0.0.0 with 11.0.0.0 but got same error

Comment: @Shyamsundarshah Judging by the date of your comment you probably have VS2013 installed. You need to replace `10.0.0.0` with `12.0.0.0`.

Comment: @SliverNinja, after making the change, I got the new error:

Comment: please see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855404/a-new-build-error-after-making-change-by-replacing-version-10-0-0-0-with-11-0-0

Answer (score 0):

Install VS2010 SP1, that should resolve your problem.

I had this problem as well, i then installed VS2010 SP1 & VS2013 SP4.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

We have VS2013 installed on the build slaves, so we fixed the issue by doing the following: 
go to C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\OfficeTools and open theMicrosoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets file.

Replace all 11.0.0.0 with 12.0.0.0.