# VSTO Add-In build Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsto, excel-2007, excel-addins

I try to build my Excel 2007 add-in in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 environment. I had programmed it a few months ago. I have Office 2007 installed. I had the same problem as in this link: [Build Error + Creating VSTO addin for excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376771/build-error-creating-vsto-addin-for-excel-2010). After internet searches I have seen that others suggest the same solution and seems it works. I applied the same solution but I still cannot build the project. Problem now says:

```
The "SetInclusionListEntry" task could not be loaded from the assembly
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a. Could not load file or assembly 
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the 
file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly  
and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that 
implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

Obviously I still have problem  related to  declarations. I have downloaded and reinstalled Office PIARedist.exe (Primary Interop Assemblies) and vstor_redist.exe (VSTO runtime) expecting that Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll file is updated or my C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets file gets correct.

Comment: The VSTO stuff is a bit dodgy sometimes.  I've found that it's sometimes easier to proceed by creating a new project - which will hopefully compile.  Then gradually adding your existing project to it, bit by bit.  I've had to do this a few times.  As far as I could tell, the end projects were identical, but there was clearly some hidden difference, because the newer one worked whilst the old one didn't.  Obviously this is a bit of a pain, but you can waste your life away trying to fix things like this, as the error messages can be quite esoteric.

Comment: @steveo40 I started to think that way either but I did not give up yet because addin is a quite large project.